# Conditional cumulative SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
| key | idStudent | idCourse | hourCourse | mark |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
|   0 |         1 |        1 |         10 |   78 |
|   1 |         1 |        2 |         20 |   60 |
|   2 |         1 |        4 |         10 |   45 |
|   3 |         3 |        1 |         10 |   90 |
|   4 |         3 |        2 |         20 |   70 |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
```

Using a simple query, I can show student with their weighted average according to `hourCourse` and `mark`:

```
SELECT idStudent,
       SUM( hourCourse * mark ) / SUM( hourCourse ) AS WeightedAvg
  FROM `test`.`test`
  GROUP BY idStudent;
+-----------+-------------+
| idStudent | WeightedAvg |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |     60.7500 |
|         3 |     76.6667 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

But now I need to select the registers until the cumulative sum of `hourCourse` per student reaches a threshold. For example, for a threshold of 30 `hourCourse`, only the following registers should be taken into account:

```
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
| key | idStudent | idCourse | hourCourse | mark |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
|   0 |         1 |        1 |         10 |   78 |
|   1 |         1 |        2 |         20 |   60 |
|   3 |         3 |        1 |         10 |   90 |
|   4 |         3 |        2 |         20 |   70 |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------+
```

`key` 2 is not taken into account, because `idStudent` 1 already reached 30 `hourCourse` with `idCourse` 1 and 2.

Finally, the query solution should be the following:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| idStudent | WeightedAvg |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |     66.0000 |
|         3 |     76.6667 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Is there any way to create an inline query for this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The criteria while selecting the courses is from highest to the lowest mark.
**Edit:** Registers are included while the cumulative sum of hourCourse is less than 30. For instance, two registers of 20 hours each would be included (sum 40), and the following not.

Comment: What's the criteria to select the courses that would make up 30 hours?
for example, a student attends courses of 10, 5, 5 10 and 20, how would you pick the courses?

Comment: And what happens if e.g. they only have two courses both with `hourCourse = 20`, thereby exceeding a threshold of 30?

Comment: This is called bin packing problem. Sample article and solution http://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/sql/binpacking/intro.html

Comment: @Neverever I edited to add the criteria. Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan, it should include a minimal set of courses (ordered from highest to lowest mark) where the sum of hourCourse >= 30. Question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulative sums per idStudent in a sub-query, then only select the results where the cumulative sum is <= 30:

```
select idStudent,
       SUM( hourCourse * mark ) / SUM( hourCourse ) AS WeightedAvg
from
(
  SELECT t.*,
  case when @idStudent<>t.idStudent
    then @cumSum:=hourCourse
    else @cumSum:=@cumSum+hourCourse
  end as cumSum,
  @idStudent:=t.idStudent
  FROM `test` t,
  (select @idStudent:=0,@cumSum:=0) r
  order by idStudent, `key`
) t
where t.cumSum <= 30
group by idStudent;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5d07/23

Comment: I noticed you added criteria about highest to lowest mark for ordering since I posted my answer.  If you change the sub-query to `order by idStudent, mark`, that should get the correct ordering.  I'm also matching at exactly 30 hours, which your test cases fit, so my code will not handle the case correctly where the total doesn't exactly hit 30 - it will stop short.  Let me see if I can fix that...

Comment: Yes, but my major problem was to deal with the conditional, since I'm not so familiar with that in SQL. Also, I guess the "problem of 30h" could be fixed with a minor change. Honestly, I'm still checking the possibilities, but I thank you for a good reference.